# Replace \n with new line char in command output in LInux

Tags: linux, sed, replace, format, tr

I have a command which gives a big text and I want to replace all the `\n`s with actual new line char. Tried `<my command> | tr '\\n' '\n'` but its replacing `n`s as well along with `\n`s

```
echo $aa
Kanil\nSigtia

echo $aa | tr "\\\n" '\n'
Ka
il

Sigtia
```

I want

```
Kanil
Sigtia
```

or

```
Kanil

Sigtia
```

Dont mind either, its just for some logs, to make them readable

Comment: Can you try to use `echo -e`, this should honor escape characters.

Comment: yeah `echo -e` does the trick but I will have to wrap my command. Found another way ````my command | sed 's/\\n/\
/g' ```